# border-left not working in Safari

Tags: css, safari, border, html

I want to use  to simulate a cursor by adding the following class to it.

```
.cursor {
    border-left: 1px solid red;
    margin-right: -1px;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

It works perfectly fine in Firefox. However, nothing is shown in Safari. I've been trying many different values. It seems like border-left is not understood by Safari although w3c claims that it's supported by all major browsers.
 Can someone please help me fix this problem?
 Thanks,

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle of what you are doing? border-left is most certainly supported!

Comment: Safari has no problem whatsoever with border-left.  Post more code or post a JSFiddle.

Comment: @Sparky - From the looks of the code, I think it's a text cursor, not mouse.

Comment: I'm with Sparky and Rich on this one -- border-left works fine in Safari. Can you post a full example? What element are you applying the style to? We'll need the markup as well as the styling.

Comment: Yes it's text cursor. I've posted my code to JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/chepukha/aUegb/2/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to work fine for me, using your exact code. I've [created a jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9hBMh/1/), which displays a red "caret" in Safari.

Is there a particular Safari version you're having problems with? Does the jsFiddle shown work for you? It uses only the code you've provided.

[image: Caret displaying in Safari 5.0.5 on OS X 10.6.7]

On further investigation, it seems that the span must have content in order to show the border. I'm not sure exactly why -- perhaps Safari is "optimising out" the empty span, or giving it zero height, or something like that.

This appears to be a WebKit issue, as the same behaviour occurs in Chrome. As a workaround, if you set a height on the span, it seems to work. If I change your CSS to:

```
.cursor {
    border-left: solid 1px red;
    margin-right: -1px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 1em;
}
```

...that is, adding a height to the span, then your border displays whether or not it has content. Therefore I guess what's going on is that without content, WebKit is giving no height to your span, and therefore no border. Which is perfectly sensible behaviour, really.

Here is [your original jsfiddle, with a height added, that works in Safari and Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/cdvLD/).

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I've tested with something simpler and it works. I guess it's some error somewhere else in my code but I didn't find out yet. I've posted it here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/chepukha/aUegb/2/)

Comment: @chepukha Aha! Having compared our code, here's the difference -- you don't have anything in your span. If you add *anything at all* in the span, the border appears in Safari (e.g. `<span class="cursor">&nbsp;</span>` -- adding just a non-breaking space -- makes your example work.) Interesting!

Comment: @Matt Gibson add that to your answer; it's clearly the issue.

Comment: @Thomas Funny you should say that, I was typing as you were commenting. Odd, though. And a quick Google for "Safari empty span" doesn't through up anything too enlightening that I can see. Interesting problem.

Comment: @Matt Gibson i noticed the same issue in Google Chrome; you beat me to it. :)  It's not a bug; it's just that Webkit will (quite reasonably) not give the span any width if there's nothing inside. With no width, there's nothing to display the border on.

Comment: @Matt: nice trick. Thanks a lot.  @Thomas: yes, exact same thing happened with Chrome.

Comment: @Thomas @chepukha Thanks. Giving it height seems to work; I'm guessing without content, the span is zero-height. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I think Safari gets it correct.  No content => zero width/height => no border.  And the OP should have posted his HTML along with the CSS.

Comment: That however means I must add a blank in order to show my cursor. It's not really what I want. Is there any work around with this?

Comment: @chepukha I've updated my answer -- if you give the `span` an explicit height then you don't need to do the ugly workaround. You can experiment with heights, but from the look of your example, `1em` or similar might be all you need.

Comment: @Matt: Awesome. You're great. Another +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

**border-left** style works on safari v1.0+

**See my code snipped that I've just tested on Safari 5.0.2 and it worked:**

http://jsfiddle.net/DqhfJ/1/

in fact all css tags that you provided - work in Safari 1.0+ , except **display** tag (it works in Safari 1.3.2+)

Comment: no this does not work on Safari. I've tested. Let say I have <span id="mySpan"></span>. Then, $('#mySpan').addClass('cursor') It will show me a red bar in Firefox, but in Safari, I get nothing.

Comment: I think Dimitriy is right.Why did someone voted him down?  Anyway, here is what I'm doing in JSFiddle. Can someone point out my error pls? http://jsfiddle.net/chepukha/aUegb/2/   Thanks

Comment: @chepukha: select jQuery from "Choose framework" on the left. And also setInterval accepts static function name, in quotes. Ex: var t = setInterval('myFunction()', 1000); And t is a handler which can be used to clearInterval(t);

Comment: @Dmitriy: thanks, I've fixed it. It's my first time using JSFiddle. It actually works the way I wrote in Firefox but still does not work in Safari 5.0.5. I'll try using static function name as suggested.

Comment: @Dmitriy: Matt pointed out the issue. It behaves slightly btw Safari and FF. I would accept your answer 2 if there's option to accept more than 1 answer. Anyway, thanks a lot for your quick response and eager to help. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Indeed; +1 for battling away and providing a working example, which is all I did, too, really.